# Symfony doctrine peak memory manytomany retrieve count relation

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have an entity Routage and and entity Contact. They are connected with a relationship Many-To-Many.
I created a function in my repository of the Routing entity to retrieve the routes and the associated number of contacts:

```
public function getRoutages(Revue $Revue)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("Routage")
        ->leftJoin("Routage.contacts", "Contact")
        ->addSelect("Routage")
        ->addSelect("Contact")
        ->andWhere('Routage.revue = :Revue')
        ->setParameter('Revue', $Revue)
    ;
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

And in my entity Routage i have created this to get the number of contacts :

```
public function getNbContact(){
    return count($this->getContacts());
}
```

And when i use call Routage.getNbContacts() i have a peak memory up to 178MB.

Do you have any solution ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem with that approach is that you are using doctrine directly, but... what is the problem?, the hydration process is one of the most heavy process on doctrine, you are asking for all contacts for example 100 but doctrine have to hydrate each one and then you just count it.

I suggest to ask to the repository that count without hydration and do that count on database.

for example:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("Routage")
        ->leftJoin("Routage.contacts", "Contact")
        ->addSelect("count(Contact.id)")
        ->addSelect("Routage.id)")
        ->andWhere('Routage.revue = :Revue')
        ->addGroupBy("Routage.id")
        ->setParameter('Revue', $Revue)
    ;
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Just remember to add groupby to each column you need on the select.

I can't taste it, so is posible that i have something wrong, but thats is the idea.

Hope it helps,

If need more info tell me.

Comment: Thanks @sergiosusa for your explications ! It works perfectly !

Comment: excellent, glad to hear it. Remember mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
public function getRoutages(Revue $Revue)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("Routage")
        ->leftJoin("Routage.contacts", "Contact")
        ->addSelect("Routage")
        ->addSelect("Contact")
        ->andWhere('Routage.revue = :Revue')
        ->setParameter('Revue', $Revue)
    ;
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Try

```
public function getRoutages(Revue $Revue)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("Routage")
        ->leftJoin("Routage.contacts", "Contact")
        ->andWhere('Routage.revue = :Revue')
        ->setParameter('Revue', $Revue)
    ;
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

When you do

```
$this->createQueryBuilder("Routage")
     ->leftJoin("Routage.contacts", "Contact")
```

You are already doing your `select`